# Do one or both of these methods follow the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I have a `School` class which holds a list of students and a `Student` class has a list of awards and grades like the following:

```
public class School
{
    List<Student> Students {get;set;}
}

public class Student
{
    List<Grade> Grades {get;set;}
    List<Award> Awards{get;set;}
}
```

I have a copy method that copies the `Student's Awards and/or Grades` from one `School` to another.  You have the option of just coping the `Student to a new school or the Student and his/her Awards and/or Grades`.  Which of the following follows the `Single Responsibility Principle` and why does it follow it and if neither do, why do they not?  The first example Copies the students and takes booleans to determine if `Grades and Awards` should be copied:

```
CopyStudent(Student student, bool copyGrades, bool copyAwards)
{
   //Copy Student

   if(copyGrades)
   {
      //Copy Grades
   }

   if(copyAwards)
   {
      //Copy Awards
   }
}
```

The above includes the copying for the `Grades` and `Awards` in the `CopyStudent` class.  Does that follow `SRP` or is better to break coping grades and awards into separate methods such as:

```
CopyGrades(List<Grade> grades)
{
    //Copy grades
}

CopyAwards(List<Award> awards)
{
    //Copy awards
}
```

So the above methods would be called from the `CopyStudent` method.

Comment: There's no difference between copying grades and copying the name, they're all part of copying the student so both adhere to the SRP in a way. It's much better style to extract them into separate methods if they take more than a few lines to keep a clean overview though.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - OK, I initially went with the second way because it made the code cleaner and more readable to me and it seems you agree with that, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Readability is one of the most important aspects of code, the importance of it cannot be overstated.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen already mentioned in the comments, it is always a good idea to separate methods so the second approach seems better at a first glance.

You could argue though that in some cases you just want to "copy a student" - no more no less. And in these cases - [to avoid code duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - you need something like `CopyStudent()` as in your first approach. The flags `copyGrades` and `copyAwards` on the other hand are a bit [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Still the two approaches do not necessarily contradict each other. How about this:

```
CopyGrades(List<Grade> grades)
{
    //Copy grades
}

CopyAwards(List<Award> awards)
{
    //Copy awards
}

CopyStudent(Student student)
{
   CopyGrades(student.grades)
   CopyAwards(student.awards)
}
```

---

In general I find the SRP hard to grasp. In some cases it *is* difficult to determine whether it is met or not. Some hints and heuristics:

- Describe what the function / method / class / module *does*. Is this represented by its name? Do you need more than one sentence (concatenated by "and", "or", "but")? If the second answer is "yes", reconsider your design.
- [A responsibility is a reason to *change*](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) (Robert C. Martin)
- [Another view](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) of "Uncle Bob", this time with emphasis on people and design (and code, of course)